# Python Find data in excel by Date

Tags: python, excel, pandas

So I'm trying to get two CSV's to be outputted by splitting them based upon the date. however, whenever I try to to do this I  get a syntax error when calling the heading title

```
ufp = pd.read_excel('pythoncsv/C20190723.xlsx')

ufp.head()

"Segmentation   Account#    Last Name   First Name  State   Phone   Alt Phone   Language    Therapy Last Order Date Next Order Date Customer Type"
```

Last order is shown as a datime64

```
ts = pd.to_datetime('2019-04-25')
```

so this is the jist of the code I want to work.

```
ufp.loc[ufp.'Last Order Date' >= ts, :]
```

but i get

```
 File "<ipython-input-22-0e4a7bef835a>", line 1
    ufp.loc[ufp.'Last Order Date' >= ts, :]
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is the way I'm phrasing the column wrong? I'm extremely new to python so it's possible I just don't get what I'm doing.

Comment: Have you tried `ufp['Last Order Date']`? Due to Python's dynamic nature, pandas allows  you to refer to a column as `ufp.ColumnName` (the attribute syntax) or `ufp['ColumnName']` (the subscripting syntax). Not all column names make for valid attribute names so I mostly avoid the  first syntax as a matter of personal style.

Comment: Also your code is a bit verbose. `ufp[ufp['Last Order Date'] > ts]` will achieve what you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ufp.loc[ufp['Last Order Date'] >= ts, :]
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

Columns (when talking about them as attributes of a data frame using `.column_name` notation) do not require quotation marks like they would when referenced elsewhere. To access columns this way you will need to remove the spaces in the column label. For instance, you can refer to `ufp.Last_Order_Date` but not `ufp.Last Order Date`.

Try what Ramesh suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness: starting with version [0.25.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.25.0.html#other-enhancements), you can also use [query](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/panda.DataFrame.query.html#pandas.DataFrame.query) with column names that contain spaces by surrounding them in backticks:

```
ufp.query(`Last Order Date` >= @ts)
```